# Where is the address space of a process stored?

Tags: linux

Where is the address space of a process stored ? Is it on disk or in main memory ?

Comment: This is a very broad (and basic) question.  A web search of your title yielded [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9414565/3960947 "Understanding virtual address and virtual address space"), [this](https://www.quora.com/What-is-virtual-address-space-and-where-it-is-stored-Why-we-need-VA-if-we-are-about-to-store-limited-data-in-memory-only-of-its-capacity), and about 250 million others — how many of them have you already read?

Comment: There is so much (about 245 million) half-baked info on this. I like the shortness and weirdness of this Q a lot! But check out my answer, if you want.

Comment: dasblinkenlight's explanation is a children's story.

Comment: The quora post is a OK introduction, but this is just nonsense: *Where is it stored? I would say no where in the VAS as the name says Virtual. Every process running will have the same address space how small in size it may be.*

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "address space". The actual contents? Both on disk and in main memory, and swapping exchanges those. The address space *mapping* (e.g. which files are mmaped)? The virtual memory mapping? Something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A process' address space is *virtual*; the addresses can refer to main memory, registers on hardware devices, files on disk (see the `mmap` system call), etc. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space), for example, on more information on virtual address spaces.